# Fetching Core Data object in the background and reloading TableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data, asynchronous, afnetworking

I want to load Core Data objects in the background, and when it´s finished, should reload a TableView.
I don´t like to do all this stuff in my tableviewcontroller class so I create a second "InternetConnection" class. 
The InternetConnection class has a method called "getNewEventsWithDateSpan"

```
//The method call in TableViewController.m
    InternetConnection *connectionForWeekEvents = [[InternetConnection alloc]init];
    connectionForWeekEvents.delegate = self;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    [connectionForWeekEvents getNewEventsWithDateSpan: [self.date_span intValue]];
});
```

In this method I build up a AFURLSessionManager (I´m using AFNetworking 2.0) and peform a dataTaskWithRequest and when it finished I call a delegate method which I implement in TableViewController.m

```
//Method in InternetConnection.m

-(void)getNewEventsWithDateSpan:(NSInteger)datespan{
//#Doing Init Stuff
 AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:self.sessionConfiguration];
[[manager dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {

// #I store the receive data in core data
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;

    if (httpResponse.statusCode ==200) {
        [delegate dataComplete]; //<- Delegate Method
    }else {
        [delegate errorLoading]; //<- Delegate Method
    }
}
}
```

Finally, I reload the TableView.

```
-(void)dataComplete{
NSLog(@"All Datas were load");

dispatch_after(0, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    _fetchedResultsController = nil;
    [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
});
```

This way it works and I get the right results, but is this a good way to do it? I perhaps have to load more data, and it might be taking a while to fetch all the data. The User could left the tableview and switch to another viewcontroller. Are there any problems with the delegate methods? Should I do it another way?

For advices I would be very grateful!

Comment: If there is larger data then for that you could show **Progress/activity** view till all data is fetched and loaded in tableview so it will also stop user from switching from one screen to another while download is in progress. So for that you could start progress/activity view in **dispatch_sync block** so your view will not be affected and download or fetching of data could be done in **dispatch_async block**. Hope this might help you out.

Comment: thank you for your answer! Thats a way I can do this (maybe i do it this way). But my aim was it, to download things in the background and save in the database. When the TableView is the Current View then reload the tableview, if theres another view the current screen, then only save it in the database. Are there possibiltiy to do it with IOS7 Background Fetch? Or use another thread? Also a problem is, that a save things in my Core Data database and load things from it.

Comment: `MagicalRecord` is a great tool when working with `CoreData`... It has some nice features to work with background tasks, which **is not easy with `CoreData` since `CoreData` is not thread safe**....

Comment: what´s your advice for handle my "problem". Is it worth to do it in a background task, for example with MagicalRecord, or should I do it in a dispatch_sync block? I don´t want to have problems with a slow, chrashing app. But of course it would be a nice feature when i can load things in the background, i display when its necerssary..

Comment: @mkersche17 you could vote up me if my info was useful to you ! As far I have read about background fetch its basically when you have to handle some stuff of your app as it enters in background and also for fetching purpose. Sorry not much idea on bacground fetch. Got this [Link](http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-background-fetch-programming/) might help you !